# font changes in the middle of the text on mobile version (fairphone)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, fonts, font-face

I created a webpage with some text. when looking at the page from a mobile (to be precise, from [fairphone 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fairphone_1)), for some lines, the font changes slightly as you can see in the screenshot below (text in red rectanlges compared to the other text):

[image]

The text looks a bit more bold and the letter-spacing is less.

The HTML of the part looks like this (nothing is changed via CSS, etc.):

[image]

what can be the reason for this?